# Advantages of QuickConnect over Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, cross-platform, cordova

I'm evaluating different cross plattform mobile frameworks. I like Phonegap and think I understood how it works, but am now looking at QuickConnect and have a much harder time to figure it out, especially how it compares to Phonegap.

Can anybody help me to define the advantages or differences of QuickConnect in comparison to Phonegap?

Comment: Good luck. There are just 58 phonegap questions on SO and maybe a dozen QuickConnect. Half of those are comparison questions like this. Nobody really uses these cross-platform tools. They sound neat in theory but unless your just porting a web page, I don't think they're very useful.

Comment: Plenty of people use these cross-platform tools. I'm just finishing up an app this week that uses PhoneGap. It's especially great for web developers/designers who want to dip their toe into native app development. Added benefit: With very few modifications I can deploy to Android and have a mobile web version to boot. Phonegap has been extremely useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a year later I can say that QuickConnect *theoretically* is of the same kind, but *practically* Phonegap is the much more useful platform as its adoption is much higher, the development is done by a community and not by one guy, and seems to be moving much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend Titanium Appcelerator http://www.appcelerator.com. It works well (though with a few quirks), it's open source and completely free to use.

I've used it for iPhone development and have an app in the App Store.

They have just released version 1.5.1 of their framework which has improved Android support. I've built my app for Android, but only tested it in the emulator as I don't have an Android phone to test it fully.

## Titanium Appcelerator Pros

- Actively developed
- Commercial support available
- Javascript as development environment (could be a con)
- Supports iPhone, Android and Blackberry (commercial support currently required for Blackberry)
- Good community on their site for questions
- Can build native extensions

## Cons

- Bit fiddly to get all the parts working
- Not every feature available on every platform (for example using your own icons on Google Maps)
- It's a cross platform tool, which always has cons
- Android support was quirky in version 1.4.0 which was last time I tried it.

## Phonegap

I tried this and it didn't support any of the features I needed and seemed almost abandoned. Cannot recommend.

## QuickConnect

Haven't used it.

Comment: Titanium Appcelerator is a different kind of framework. Very brief: Phonegap/Quickconnect package a url into a native web view, Titantium translates JavaScript into native code on runtime.